# Extend TypeScript ESLint config from Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, eslint

I have followed this guide to extend my ESLint config.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#experimental-extending-the-eslint-config

The documentation states that `Note that any rules set to "error" will stop the project from building`. I have added a `.env` file with `EXTEND_ESLINT=true` in the same folder as my `package.json` file.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

As soon as this file was added I stopped getting warning from the command `npm run build`, even when using the default values in package.json:

[image]

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
},
```

If I set `.env` file to `EXTEND_ESLINT=false` the warnings start to show up again.

[image]

The reason for doing it in the first place is because I want to add the `no-multiple-empty-lines` rule like this:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [ "react-app" ],
  "rules": {
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": [
      "error",
      {
        "max": 1,
        "maxEOF": 0,
        "maxBOF": 0
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multiple-empty-lines

I think the config is correct because when I add this rule the following command will show expected result:

```
npx eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx
```

Before config change:

[image]

After config change:

[image]

Reading up on the `.env` file it says that `npm run build` will read files in the following order: `.env.production.local, .env.production, .env.local, .env`. Since I only have `.env` it should pick it up. Documentation also states this above `EXTEND_ESLINT` - `You do not need to declare REACT_APP_ before the below variables as you would with custom environment variables.`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env

I have read this thread as well but I can't see where I wen't wrong:

[How is ESLint integrated into Create React App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633005/how-is-eslint-integrated-into-create-react-app)

If I edit the `scripts` section in `package.json` to `"build": "set EXTEND_ESLINT=true && react-scripts build",` I will get the normal warnings but my added rule wont be executed anyway.

[image]