# Do React hooks really have to start with "use"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Lets' create a very simple hook `useDouble` that returns the double of a number:

```
export default function useDouble(nb) {
  return nb * 2;
}
```

The documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook) reads:

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks

But if I change `useDouble` to `double`, it still works. I even tried to call other hooks from the `double` hook, and it still works.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-gareth-usb8g?file=/src/components/WithUseDouble.js

So my question is: is naming hooks `useXxxxx` just a convention, or can it really break something somehow? And if it can, could you show an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

React hook definition according to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook):

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

A perfect definition of a custom hook would be (notice the removal of "use" prefix and "may"):

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function **that calls other Hooks**.

So we could **distinguish** between **helper functions** and **custom hooks**.

**But**, we can't tell if certain functions are actually using hooks (we do know in runtime). Thats why we use [static code analyzing tools](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Static_program_analysis) (like `eslint`) where we analyze text (lexical) and not meaning (semantics).

> This convention guarantees that you can always look at a component and know where its state, Effects, and other React features might “hide”. ([Reusing Logic with Custom Hooks](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#hook-names-always-start-with-use))

> Should all functions called during rendering start with the use prefix? No. Functions that don’t call Hooks don’t need to be Hooks. ([Reusing Logic with Custom Hooks](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#should-all-functions-called-during-rendering-start-with-the-use-prefix))

> ... this convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to automatically check for violations of Rules of Hooks because we **couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of it**. ([Legacy docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook))

Hence:

```
// #1 a function
// CAN'T BREAK ANYTHING
function double(nb) {
  return nb * 2;
}

// #2 Still a function, does not use hooks
// CAN'T BREAK ANYTHING
function useDouble(nb) {
  return nb * 2;
}

// #3 a custom hook because hooks are used 
// CAN BREAK, RULES OF HOOKS
function useDouble(nb) {
  const [state, setState] = useState(nb);
  const doubleState = (n) => setState(n*2);
  return [state,doubleState];
}
```

---

> Is naming hooks useXxxxx just a convention.

Yes, to help static analyzer to warn for errors.

> Can it really break something somehow?

Example #2 can't break your application since it just a "helper function" that not violating Rules of Hooks, although there will be a warning.

> Could you show an example?

```
// #2 from above
function useDouble(nb) { return nb * 2; }

// <WithUseDouble/>
function WithUseDouble() {
  // A warning violating Rules of Hooks 
  // but useDouble is actually a "helper function" with "wrong" naming
  // WON'T break anything
  if (true) {
    return <h1>8 times 2 equals {useDouble(8)} (with useDouble hook)</h1>
  }
  
  return null;
}
```

Comment: The only reason this answer doesn't have like a million upvotes is because most of us devs don't care about the naming; we just use "use". This answer should be a model of how to write the perfect response on SO.

Comment: `if (true)` and `return null;` look kind of redundant in that example...

Comment: It's not clear why "we can't tell if certain functions are actually using hooks". As it seems, it's technically possible to do code analysis from 'use-' prefixed helper to see if it is actually using React basic or custom hooks. Is there any way to set eslint to distinguish 'use-' prefixed helpers and actual React custom hooks?

Comment: You have the example of "useDouble", the linter warns its a hook, but it isn't.

Answer (score 9):

> Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”? Please do. This
> convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to
> automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we
> couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of
> it

From [reactjs/docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook).

And in large components that use several functions, the "use" prefix also helps in easily identifying if a function is a custom hook.