# Use Hook in function result in invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently rewriting my website into a webapp with ReactJS, and have a little trouble using and understanding hooks. I wrote a custom hook "useFetch" that works, never had any problems with it until now : I am currently trying to use my hook in a function like this :

```
import useFetch from '../../../hooks/useFetch';
import {clientGenerateProcessScreen, clientClearProcessScreen} from '../../../utils/processScreens';

function myFunction (paramName, paramType, paramDesc) {
    let process_screen = clientGenerateProcessScreen ();
    let rqt_url = `/fileNameA.php`;
    if (paramType!= "a") rqt_url = `/fileNameB.php`;

    const { data, isLoading, error } = useFetch(rqt_url);
    if (!isLoading && data.success) {
        doSomethingA ();
    } else {
        showErrorMessage ();
    }
}
export default myFunction;
```

The function is called from an onClick on a react component. It should theorically work fine, however, I always end up having this error :

> Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I do not understand where the error here is. I am using my hook at the top of a function, not in a condition or anything that might break hook rules. I have tried importing React and ReactDOM in my function file, but this doesn't solve any of my issues. I am guessing I might have missed something basic or simple, yet can't find what...

Comment: You don't give any context or a reproducible example to allow fixing suggestions. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can't call a hook in a callback (like an onClick event handler). You can either call a hook in component, or in another hook. You'll have to reorganize your code around these rules.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you implemented a **custom hook**, therefore it should be prefixed with the "use" word: `useMyFunction`, for more context see [Do React hooks really have to start with "use"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151248/do-react-hooks-really-have-to-start-with-use/66151737#66151737).

Now that you know its a hook and not a util function, it must follow hooks API ("Rules of Hooks"), and one of those rules is that you must call it in a top level, i.e You CANT use it as a callback.

For solving it, it requires a logical change, its not something you have a step-by-step fixing guide, rethink its logical use.

Comment: Thank ! My hook is prefixed with "use", but as you said the issue here is that i can't use in a callback. Thanks for pointing that out and have a great day ! :)