# how to add rules to ESLint in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I can't add rules or edit ESLint in a Create React App.

before version  4.0. all was ok- i had *.eslintrc.js* file with rules.
i moved to 4.0.2 and - the app stopped compiling. so i removed .eslintrc.js, and got completion back.
ok.

but now, i can't add or edit anything regarding ESLlint.

i can't add a new *.eslintrc.js*, use the old one, or config the lint in the *package.json* file like the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor) solution - all returning to completion problem.

tried to add .env file with `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true` but still the same problem.

how can you extend or Edit ESLint ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59633005/6928824, which also answers the question but provides further information

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use to edit the rules in the package.json :

for example :

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "warn"
    },
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": ["**/*.ts?(x)"],
        "rules": {
          "max-len": "warn"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```