# How to solve the error Parsing error: Missing semicolon?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am developing a search bar that performs the search by calling an api, I encounter an error: Parsing error: Missing semicolon. The error comes from this part of the code:
`const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement;`
specifically between the `event.target` and the `as`. Could someone explain me the reason of this error and how to solve it?

```
import React, { FormEvent, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Select, { SingleValue } from "react-select";
import { getCollegiate } from "../../api/drupalAPI";
import { Collegiate } from "@icofcv/common";
import Loader from "../spinner/Loader";

interface Props {
  showModal: boolean;
  closeModal: () => void;
}

export const ModalFilterCollegiate: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  showModal,
  closeModal,
}) => {
  const [collegiateList, setCollegiateList] = useState<Collegiate[]>([]);
  const [collegiateSearch, setCollegiateSearch] = useState("");

  const searchForCollegiates = async (query: String): Promise<Collegiate[]> => {
    const result = await fetch(`/collegiate?filter=${query}`);
    return (await result.json()).results;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const query = encodeURIComponent(collegiateSearch);
      const response = await searchForCollegiates(query);
      setCollegiateList(response);
    })();
  }, [collegiateSearch]);

  const search = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = event.target as HTMLFormElement;
    const input = form.querySelector("#searchText") as HTMLInputElement;
    setCollegiateSearch(input.value);
    input.value = "";
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        {showModal ? (
          <>
            <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
              <div className="relative p-2 w-full max-w-2xl h-full md:h-auto">
                {/*content*/}
                <div className="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow">
                  {/*header*/}
                  <div className="flex justify-between items-start px-4 py-3 rounded-t border-b">
                    <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Buscar Colegiado</h3>
                    <button
                      className="text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm p-1.5 ml-auto inline-flex items-center"
                      onClick={closeModal}
                    >
                      <svg
                        aria-hidden="true"
                        className="w-5 h-5"
                        fill="currentColor"
                        viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                      >
                        <path
                          fill-rule="evenodd"
                          d="M4.293 4.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 8.586l4.293-4.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414L11.414 10l4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 11.414l-4.293 4.293a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414L8.586 10 4.293 5.707a1 1 0 010-1.414z"
                          clip-rule="evenodd"
                        ></path>
                      </svg>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  {/*body*/}
                  <div className="relative px-3 py-3 flex-auto overflow-auto modal-body">
                    <form
                      className="searchForm"
                      onSubmit={(event) => search(event)}
                    >
                      <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-4">
                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
                          <label
                            htmlFor=""
                            className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600"
                          >
                            Número colegiado
                          </label>
                          <input
                            name=""
                            type="text"
                            id=""
                            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                          />
                          <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">
                            Completa este espacio
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-4">
                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
                          <label
                            htmlFor=""
                            className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600"
                          >
                            Nombre
                          </label>
                          <input
                            name=""
                            type="text"
                            id="searchText"
                            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                          />
                          <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">
                            Completa este espacio
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full group my-2">
                          <label
                            htmlFor=""
                            className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600"
                          >
                            Apellidos
                          </label>
                          <input
                            name=""
                            type="text"
                            id=""
                            className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5"
                          />
                          <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">
                            Completa este espacio
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="grid md:grid-cols-2 md:gap-4">
                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                          <label
                            htmlFor=""
                            className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600"
                          >
                            Provincia
                          </label>
                          <select className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                            <option>Cualquier Provincia</option>
                          </select>
                          <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">
                            Completa este espacio
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="relative z-0 w-full group">
                          <label
                            htmlFor=""
                            className="block mb-2 text-xs font-medium text-stone-600"
                          >
                            Tipo
                          </label>
                          <select className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5">
                            <option>Seleccionar tipo</option>
                            <option>Ejercientes</option>
                            <option>No ejercientes</option>
                            <option>Honorarios</option>
                            <option>Colegiados de honor</option>
                          </select>
                          <p className="mt-2 text-xs text-red-600 hidden">
                            Completa este espacio
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="flex items-center justify-end px-4 py-3 border-t border-solid border-slate-200 rounded-b gap-2">
                        <button
                          className="btn text-black text-sm background-transparent px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none focus:ring-teal-600 focus:border-teal-600"
                          type="button"
                          onClick={closeModal}
                        >
                          Cancelar
                        </button>
                        <button
                          className="btn bg-teal-600 hover:bg-teal-700 text-white text-sm active:bg-teal-700 px-8 outline-none focus:outline-none"
                          type="button"
                        >
                          Buscar
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  {/*footer*/}

                  {collegiateList.map((collegiate) => (
                    <tr key={collegiate.id} className="bg-white border-b">
                      <td className="py-2 px-6">{collegiate.color}</td>
                      <td className="py-2 px-6">{collegiate.collegiate}</td>
                      <td className="py-2 px-6">{collegiate.firstname}</td>
                      <td className="py-2 px-6">{collegiate.lastname}</td>
                      <td className="py-2 px-6">{collegiate.provincia}</td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="opacity-25 fixed inset-0 z-40 bg-black"></div>
          </>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Typescript Type Cast Issue - Parsing Error: Missing Semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67412890/react-typescript-type-cast-issue-parsing-error-missing-semicolon)