# For flat config, how do I run ESLint from the command line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eslint, eslint-flat-config

*For `eslint.config.js` ([flat config](https://eslint.org/blog/2022/08/new-config-system-part-2)), what command should I use when linting `*.js` files recursively from the command line?* <sup>1</sup>

---

With `eslintrc.js` or `eslintrc.json`, I have been using `npx eslint . --ext .js`, as suggested [here](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#--ext-example).
Until now, it always worked fine.

But when I try that with `eslint.config.js`, the response in the command line is :

> Invalid option '--ext' - perhaps you meant '-c'?
> You're using eslint.config.js, some command line flags are no longer available.
> Please see https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface for details.

I didn't find any solution at the suggested link.

My `eslint.config.js` is in the directory where I try to run the lint command. <sup>2</sup>

```js
import eslintJs from '@eslint/js';
import globals from 'globals';

export default [
  eslintJs.configs.recommended,
  {
    // files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.cjs', '**/*.mjs'], // = default, not needed
    languageOptions: { globals: { ...globals.node } },
    rules: { 'no-unused-vars': ['warn', { argsIgnorePattern: '^_' }] },
  },
];
```

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "flat-config",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.52.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "type": "module"
}
```

I ran `npm install` before running `npx eslint . --ext .js`.

For demo purposes, I have a small `bad-code.js` file :

```js
const hiUnused = 'hi there';
const hello='Hello world';
const unusedFunc = function(unusedVariable) { console.log('hi!') }
consoler.log(hello);
```

If and when ESLint works, I expect it to respond with three warnings and one error.

```
warning  'hiUnused'       never used
warning  'unusedFunc'     never used
warning  'unusedVariable' never used
 error   'consoler'       not defined
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
I include the [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) tag because I expect the corresponding question and answer(s) to be very similar for [TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/typescript/info).

<sup>2</sup>
I include the line `files: ['**/*.js', '**/*.cjs', '**/*.mjs'],` to indicate that [*by default, ESLint matches `**/*.js`, `**/*.cjs`, and `**/*.mjs`*](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#specifying-files-and-ignores).
Commenting out or leaving it in should therefore not make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What command should I use when linting `*.js` files recursively from the command line?*

Try : <sup>1</sup>

```
npx eslint **/*.js
```

This will lint all `*.js` files in the current directory and all its subdirectories. 
The command `npx eslint **/*.js` works just as fine for the old-school `.eslintrc.*` type of files as it does for the new `eslint.config.js` ones.

For your demo file, `bad-code.js`, ESLint responds :

```
1:7   warning  'hiUnused' is assigned a value but never used    no-unused-vars
3:7   warning  'unusedFunc' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
3:29  warning  'unusedVariable' is defined but never used.
                  Allowed unused args must match /^_/u          no-unused-vars
4:1   error    'consoler' is not defined                        no-undef
```

[image: ESLint responds with three warnings and one error.]

<sup>^ click to enlarge</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>
This is from [the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files-new#configuration-file-resolution).
Just filter out all the config stuff. 
(Disregard `ESLINT_USE_FLAT_CONFIG=true` and `--config some-other-file.js`.)